# Validating email against multiple same words in react-native

Tags: validation, react-native

I'm facing a problem while validating an Email in react-native.
Currently I'm using `email-validator` and it's working fine. I'm not using email verification in my App, so I need to check precisely whether input is email or not.

I'm looking for a technique which can identify following as an invalid email because it has a word more then once after `@`

```
User@mail.com
User@mail.mail.com
User@mail.com.com.uk
User@mail.com.com
```

Valid email should be like this.

```
User@mail.com
User@mail.com.uk
User@mail.com.edu.uk
```

Comment: Are you looking for a regular expression or is a full function acceptable?

Comment: I've seen some regular expressions but thy are not completely reliable. My requirements are only to remove same words from email after @ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression would probably be more efficient if anyone else want's to provide one, but here's one way to do it in a function:

```js
var email = "User@mail.mail.com";
let findDuplicates = (arr) => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) != index);
let hasDuplicate = (test) => findDuplicates(test.split("@")[1].split(".")).length > 0
console.log(hasDuplicate(email));
```